# Normalize value from [-x|x] to [-1|1]

Tags: java, math

I want to normalize a value between `-x` and `x` to `-1` and `1`.

I thought about `value / Math.abs(value)`, but the problem is if 
value is 0 that doesn't work.

Is there a possibility without if and else, so with one operation?

Maybe i should add, that the value only can be -x, x, or 0. nothing between.

Comment: As per you what is the except result for Math.abs(0). As per my understand it return 0 only. Any value divide by 0 it will give exception.

Comment: You need to know what `x` is as well as what `value` is.

Comment: (Why -2?) Neglecting floating point precision, does the transformation have to be invertible? *I.e.* must every unique input value map to a different normalised value?

Comment: i dont understand the downvotes. i know that i cannot divide through zero. that was only an idea, and i also said why i isnt working.
no. there are only 3 possible values, -x, x and 0. nothing between

Comment: I can see a few reasons for downvotes: 1. you've buried the fact that the value has three possibilities at the end, making the question unclear and not useful; 2. you've restricted it to not use conditionals for no valid reason; 3. you've not bother to give the simple code using conditionals, which would have instantly clarified #1; 4. 2&3 combine to give the appearance that you've not done any research effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the java.lang.Integer class. There are some nice static methods to help you out, mainly `Integer.signum(int)`

That will do the job, if you want 0 to convert to 1 too, add a check for 0:

```
int x = value == 0 ? 1 : Integer.signum(value);
```

Edit: Long contains likewise methods that do the job with long.

Alternately, no-if code; probably slower, but OP specifically asked for it:

```
final static int[] TABLE = { -1, 1 (or 0), 1 };
int x = TABLE[Integer.signum(value) + 1];
```

Comment: @T_01 Integer.signum() is *not* if else. And you havent defined what you want to do with zero; so before nitpicking answers, maybe make your *question* clear?

Comment: whats the problem with my question?
the if else is the "? :"
Sorry that im not perfect in english... 
AGAIN: I have a value. it is -x, x, or 0. only this 3 possibilities. Now i want to have a method norm(int val) which should return -1, 1, or 0, but without condition checking, like "? :" or if else.

Comment: @T_01 And *thats* exactly what Integer.signum() already does. Did you even make the effort to take a look at it? And you never defined (until *now*) what the desired result is when the input is 0 - take a look at your original question.

Comment: okay okay, sorry. 
The alternative you posted is really nice. but are you sure, its slower? the reason why i want to avoid if else and YES, "= ? :" is if else actually, is im writing an opengl engine... and too much if else can slow down the whole process.

Comment: @T_01 Ever heard of term *premature optimization*? Such microoptimizations come *last*, after your code *works*. And they usually get you only a miniscule improvement in performance while they make your code unreadable. Focus of improving algorithms (such a lazy calculation etc.). They yield far more bang for your time. And if you insist on microoptimizing; only one way to find out: mesasure it. And don't expect consistent results across VM versions or CPU models :)

Comment: hm actually youre right. it didnt look for me like microoptimization, but actually it is. 
So, i did it with if(val == 0){state = 0;}else{state = val / abs(val)}

Comment: @T_01 If you need 0 for 0 input, Integer.signum() is the way to go (Its *defined* to do exactly that). If you adopt a handmade solution, put it into a static method, don't inline it manually (the JIT *will* automatically inline where possible). Manual inlining only creates trouble with maintainability for virtually no gains.

Answer (score 4):

```
value / Math.abs(x)
```

is what you need. `x` should never be zero obviously.

Also you should think how to handle the case when `value > x`.

Comment: @BackSlash The assumption is that `x >= abs(value)`.

Comment: if `x` is `0`, then it is already normalized anyway. @PeterLawrey no, `Math.abs(x) > 0` is the assumption.

Comment: +1, yup this is correct. And without loss of generality, you can drop the `abs`.

Comment: @T_01 normalization doesn't make any sense if x is 0. if you are unsure about input you must have if.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you only want the sign of the number.  You can use

```
double sign = Math.signum(x);
```

Note: this return NaN for NaN and 0 for 0.

If you expect `0` to return a different value there alternatives.

Note: a condition might be simpler/clearer. e.g.

```
int sign = x < 0 ? -1 : +1;
```

or

```
int sign = x > 0 ? +1 : x < 0 : -1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a mathematic method, I started from -5 to 5 and converted in -1 to 1

```
    max=1;
    min=-1;
    maxold=-5;
    minold=5;

    value=2;

    newvalue= (max-min)/(maxold-minold)*(value-minold)+min;
    alert(newvalue);
```

Comment: Which simplifies to `value / max` (assuming `min = -max` and `minold = -maxold`). Plough through the algebra and you'll see this.

Comment: i dont know maxold or minold.

Comment: maxOld and minOld are your -x/x .I uses this formula just because with this you can vary a range from -x to y where x!=y